# Position of question mark when sentence doesn't end with question

Tags: punctuation, question-mark

This is something that has always bugged me.  I am never sure where to place the question mark, or whether to place it at all when the end of the sentence does not finish with a question, or a number of questions from the begining

For example:

> The question nagging me is to what
>   extent can we encapsulate all what we
>   observe in nature into a set of simple
>   computational rules, within which we
>   can leverage our existing knowledge.

Should the final full-stop (period) be replaced by a question mark? Or perhaps even the comma?

Comment: In this case, replace "can we" with "we can" and you're golden. Generally speaking, you can always rephrase an embedded question into its less questiony form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A question within a sentence should be preceded by a comma, and end with a question mark.

> I am wondering, how long has that fish statue been there?
>
> There are three important issues that this committee must address. What was the chairman doing in that YouTube video? is not among them.

If a question is particularly long or complex, then for clarity it could begin with a capital letter.

> In the daydreams of my youth I would look at the clouds and wonder, Will I find happiness and fulfillment soon after getting a business administration degree, or must I amortize my well-being return on investment over the next seven to ten calendar years?

The sentence in the original question ends with a subordinate clause that does not, by itself, ask a question (“within which we can leverage our existing knowledge”). This is modifying a noun phrase that is part of the question (“set of simple computational rules”). Therefore, this subordinate clause is part of the original question, and should end with a question mark.

Putting all of this together, I would punctuate the sentence like this:

> The question nagging me is, To what extent can we encapsulate all what we observe in nature into a set of simple computational rules, within which we can leverage our existing knowledge?

(Some of this advice is based on *The Chicago Manual of Style 15th Edition* §6.55 and §6.71.)

Comment: Is that second quoted example ("There are three ...") actually correct? Doesn't a question mark end a sentence? If so, shouldn't the "is" be capitalised? Maybe it'd be easier on my brain if it was in quote marks, which would probably work in work that example, but not all examples..

Comment: @naught101 - That example appears as I intended, and I believe it is correct, though uncommon. There are similar examples in the cited sections of the CMOS, and I have also noticed it a few times in the wild. I do think it likely that most people would surround a question like that with quotation marks, since a mid-sentence question mark is rarely taught or used. But I also think that the bare form is often better, and I personally prefer the example sentence as it appears (for whatever that's worth). Quotation marks would make it—to me—incorrectly emphasize the form of the specific question.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a question mark at the end of your sentence... if it were an [interrogative one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_sentence).
But I find it rather descriptive, and not so much a request for information.

However, with other punctuations, you could make it more like a dialog, in which a question would more naturally be presented:

> The question nagging me is: "to what extent can we encapsulate all what we observe in nature into a set of simple computational rules, within which we can leverage our existing knowledge?"

Comment: I would say that the quotation marks are not really necessary. The key here is the colon, I think it is enough to justify the question mark.

Comment: @RegDwight: I agree. I added them for emphasis.