# Placement of question mark when terminal quote has no question mark but sentence does

Tags: question-mark, quotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question mark usage/position when sentence ends with a declarative quotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/question-mark-usage-position-when-sentence-ends-with-a-declarative-quotation)

If I'm quoting something someone said and the quote does not have a question mark, but I want to end the sentence with a question mark, would it be

> Are you sure she said "Spicy?"

or

> Are you sure she said "Spicy"?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/question-mark-usage-position-when-sentence-ends-with-a-declarative-quotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write

> Are you sure she said "Spicy"?

See for example Jane Straus's [Blue book of grammar and punctuation](http://grammarbook.com/punctuation/quotes.asp).

Comment: What about a period?

Answer (score 1):

The question mark goes after the quotation mark. Unlike commas and periods, a question mark that is not part of the quoted text goes outside the quotation marks.

From [300 Days of Better Writing](http://hostileediting.com):

> However, if your final punctuation is a question mark, semicolon, or colon, and if that punctuation mark is not part of the quotation, then it should go outside. For example: Did the boss say “fire everyone you can”?