# (in)direct question after the copula

Tags: indirect-question

I'm wondering which of the following options is correct **in writing**:

1. The question is how do we improve our French.
2. The question is, how do we improve our French?
3. The question is: How do we improve our French?
4. The question is how we can improve our French.

Comment: All four variations work just fine, and they say the same thing.

Comment: I'd look at modern trends argued for [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/306363/punctuation-in-an-indirect-quotation/306370#306370), where report structures mimicking quote structures (<< She wished him Merry Christmas. >>), without the once mandatory (some would argue still mandatory) inverted commas are considered. // (4) is indisputably correct. / Many would accept (3), often/usually without the capital H. And more often with a dash than a colon nowadays. / I'd say (1) is too garden-pathy, but / (2) is becoming more accepted nowadays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Punctuation with "The question is..." '.', '?' or ' "... ?" '](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21795/punctuation-with-the-question-is-or)

Answer (score 0):

**The question is how we improve our French.**

**The question is how we can improve our French.**

> These are indirect questions and they take the normal word order and end
>   without the question mark. The clauses beginning with question words
>   can act as  subjects, objects, complements or adverbials.
>
> E.g.  Do you know what she wanted? (object)
>
> This is *how much I did so far*. (Complement)
>
> *How you divide up the money* is your business. (subject)
>
> *I'd like to know how much it is.*

Comment: A British friend of mine wrote "The question is how do we improve our French." Was he incorrect, or simply being colloquial?

Comment: More details and a lot of examples are available here:http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/indirect-questions.html

Comment: I know standard rules. What I'm curious about is my British friend's sentence. Does that reflect general British speech, or his dialect / idiolect?

Comment: He punctuated it incorrectly. It should have been direct speech: 'The question is: "how do we improve our French?"'